# In ASP.NET 2.0, Can I have a button to browse client folder and pick a path (not file)?

Tags: asp.net, directory, picker, folderbrowserdialog

I already used a hidden file upload control to browse file and grab the file path, without really uploading it.

My question is, is there a way in ASP.NET, create a folder browse button, when it is clicked, just to browse client file system, and user can click the path and choose that path not file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do with standart ASP.NET controls which map to HTML controls. Probably it's possible if you are using Flash, Silverlight or Java applets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the only file-related HTML control is the file picker (<input type="file">).

Answer (score -2):

Use Flash for this task and invoke this actions via JS

Comment: OP says 'is there a way in ASP.NET'